# Real analysis objects defined uncountably?

Tags: real-analysis

In real analysis many if not all species are defined by always using some "countable" process for example the Riemann integral: $$\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b-a}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i^\star)$$ My basic question is is there some advanced real analysis where this "countable" process isn't used and instead we have some uncountable process?

Comment: This would probably mean something that cannot be coded in [second-order arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_arithmetic).

Comment: Countable constructions work mostly because real analysis deals with second-countable topological spaces. For general topological spaces one cannot define topology in terms of sequences. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space

Comment: Try this search: [cardinal + invariants + Ciesielski](https://www.google.com/search?q=cardinal+invariants+Ciesielski)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try the Lebesgue integral?

There is a comment in Robinson's book *Non-Standard Analysis* 
on why his chapter on integration was done using the Riemann integral and not the Lebesgue integral.  He says that there is no known "first order" definition for the Lebesgue integral.  [Such a definition would be used to apply the "transfer principle" of non-standard analysis.]

If that was true in 1966 when the book was written, is it still true today?

*Robinson, Abraham*, Non-standard analysis, Princeton, NJ: Princeton Univ. Press. xix, 293 p. (1996). [ZBL0843.26012](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0843.26012).