# Why is the standard integral the Riemann Integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory

In introductory calculus courses, you are introduced to integration via the **Riemann Integral**. Often, you are shown a diagram such as the following

[image]

which defines the Riemann Integral as the sum of the areas of these rectangles.

My question is, why are these rectangles *vertical* (domain-defined) instead of *horizontal* (range-defined) like below?

[image]

From my understanding, the horizontal orientation is known as the **Lebesgue Integral**. So then my question becomes: when is it better to use either one over the other? And also, why is that, we are introduced to the Riemann Integral over the Lebesgue Integral in introductory calculus?

Comment: It's easier to introduce the Riemann integral to students than the Lebesgue one, as you don't need measure theory.

Comment: There's a couple reasons but also counterpoints to those reasons $$$$ 1. The Lebesgue integral requires a bit more machinery in terms of measure theory to understand. However, measure theory and in particular the Radon-Nikodym theorem is used liberally in freshman level physics and engineering classes all the time so this point is rather moot. $$$$ 2. The difference between measure-theoretic (Lebesgue like) vs oriented integrals (Stokes' like) isn't apparent in math classes until a multivariable math class, so introducing the difference at an even earlier stage would not show the difference.

Comment: That said, in many cases, the Lebesgue integral is a more powerful tool than the Riemann integral (e.g. Dominated Convergence Theorem, and since it's based on measure theory, it unifies  the world of discrete series and continuous integrals in one framework).

Comment: 3.  In practical terms, to actually compute a Lebesgue integral from scratch requires a conversion to a standard Riemann integral anyway. Unless you have another mechanism in place to finish the computation, such as one of many powerful theorems that apply to Lebesgue integrals that don't apply to Riemann integrals.

Comment: ... as an example of @StefanLafon 's comment: Using only a low-end scientific calculator, compute a ten, equal -height, rectangle approximation to $$\int_0^5 x + \cos x \,\mathrm{d}x \text{.}$$  Explain in detail how to get the endpoints of your rectangles.  The world is full of uninvertible integrands.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3053942/442

Comment: @Electric The "Riemann integration but with horizontal rectangles" characterization of Lebesgue integration is misleading and a severe oversimplification of what's going on. The point of Lebesgue integration is not that vertical rectangles are replaced by horizontal ones, rather it's that arrangements of horizontal rectangles are extended through the introduction of [simple functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function).

Comment: The horizontal slices picture only gives us the Lebesgue integral if we define measure correctly. A classical notion of measure such as Jordan content will not be sufficient. Thus, the true “secret sauce” behind the Lebesgue integral is not horizontal rectangles, it is the way Lebesgue measure is defined. Note that Zygmund and Wheeden define the Lebesgue integral as the “measure of the region below the graph”; this definition makes no reference to horizontal rectangles.

Comment: @NinadMunshi the Radon-Nikodym theorem is used in freshman level physics and engineering courses? Where?

Comment: @operatorerror integrals such as $I = \int r^2 dm$ and $W=\int Vdq$ are not Riemann integrals, they are integrals with respect to the mass and charge measures, respectively. The integrals are calculated in Euclidean space via the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\rho$, the mass or charge density.

Answer (score 4):

The basic idea of the Riemann integral is to approximate the area under the graph of a function $f : [a,b] \to \mathbb R$ by sums of rectangles. Technically this is done by partitioning the domain $[a,b]$ into subintervals $J_i = [t_i,t_{i+1}]$, assocating a *lower* and an *upper rectangle* to each $J_i$ which enclose the graph of $f \mid_{J_i}$ (let us call them ad hoc "Darboux rectangles") and then forming the upper and lower Darboux sums to the partition. Alternatively you can pick a point $\xi_i \in J_i$, associate the "Riemann rectangle" $J_i \times [0,f(\xi_i)]$ and form the Riemann sum.

Both are very simple and intuititive procedures which give equivalent concepts of an integral.

Your  "horizontal rectangle approach" does not work like that; the example in your second figure is completely misleading. Of course you can cover the range of $f$ by (small) intervals, but how can you assign a horizontal rectangle to such an interval $[c,d]$? What would be the analog of a lower and an upper Darboux rectangle or a Riemann rectangle?

As an example consider the following graph $G$ of an oscillating function $f : [0,5] \to \mathbb R$:

[image]

Which horizontal rectangle would you associate to a subinterval $[c,d]$ of the $y$-axis? It does not make sense to approximate the piece $G_{[c,d]} = G \cap ([0,5] \times [c,d])$ by a single rectangle; you need more than one to nicely approximate the area. Try to do it explicitly and you will see that it is really unpleasant to make it precise.

The above example is still a "nice" one; if you have infinitely many oscillations you may need infinitely many rectangles to approximate $G_{[c,d]}$.

I conclude that a naive approximation by horizontal rectangles does not really make sense. The point is that you have to approximate the subset $S_{[c,d]} = f^{-1}([c,d])$ of the domain of $f$ by suitable rectangles $R_k$, form the union $\bigcup_k R_k \times [c,d]$ and compute its area.

Finally this leads you to the concept of measure; you have to associate to $S_{[c,d]}$ its size. And that leads to the concept of the Lebesgue integral. This is a much more complicated and less intuitive access to integration, though it is superior from a higher point of view. But for beginners I would recommend to introduce the Riemann integral.